# Find all packings of widgets by a set of requirements: is this a linear programming or combinatorial optimization, or bin packing problem??

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, packing-problem

Can not determine if this is a linear programming problem, or a combinatorial optimization problem, or even a packing problem?

> Goal is to allocate widgets from the *inventory* to fulfill all *shipping
>   orders*.
>
> - Where *inventory* is a list of different widgets that each have a price
>     (\$w), widget type (A,B,C,D) and consumer rating (0-100).
> - Where each *shipping order*  must have a total value (\$m), and
>     requires a certain percentage of some widgets with a specific type and minimum consumer
>     rating.
>
> Furthermore, if too few widgets are available in the inventory to fulfill all shipping
>   orders, each widget type can be bought from a competitor at an
>   inflated price of k*w (\$).

If this is a linear programming problem, I am not sure how to setup the problem to output a set of matches since all linear optimization problems I have previously worked with optimize a single objective value. Also not sure how to setup the objective function.

Comment: You do not define the problem sufficiently. For example, in the beginning you state that "widget type" is one of (A, B, C, D) and at the end you talk about buying a "widget type" at an inflated price --- possibly you meant "widget on the inventory list" and not "widget type"? You also don't define how the "percentage" is calculated --- is it based on the number of widgets or on their value? And is the total value of a shipping order merely a lower bound or does it have to be met exactly?

Comment: As for optimizing a single objective value, here one could minimize the number of unfulfilled shipping orders. Another possibility would be to make fulfilling all the shipping orders a constraint, and minimize, for example, the total number of widgets shipped, or the value of the widgets bought from the competitors.